# gradle trigger file copy from another task

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle task which scans the dependant jars and I want to place all the dependant jars in a new directory

Using the ResolvableDependencies API I was able to identify the source and target folders.

below are the example source and target folder

sourcePath

```
D:\Users\myuserId\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.netty\netty-handler\4.0.27.Final\91d5c8e25150759bdfce680f318e7b3e8a493b1f
```

targetPath

```
D:\sourcecode\18_04_2017\my-project\build-repo\io\netty\netty-handler\4.0.27.Final
```

I have the below task in my build.gradle

```
task myCopy(type: Copy)
```

I am invoking the task like below, but it does not work

```
myCopy.configure{
  from (sourcePath)
  into (targetPath)
}

myCopy.execute()
```

I read from another SO post that task cannot be invoked from another task and we need to specify "dependsOn" . But in my case I need to copy files within a loop and the source and target paths are derived based on the conditions in the loop.
 In such case , how can i use the gradle copy method ? Or is there any other way I can copy ?

Comment: Please provide a code example for the `for`-loop you are talking about. Also, you should **never** use the `execute` method on tasks, instead think about the conditions, that should cause your task to be executed: When and why do you need files to be copied?

Comment: Thanks for your comment . I was able to call copy from the loop based on the solution suggestd by LzerBanana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please show how you scan for those dependencies?

If you dont want to create a type `Copy` task,
you can use the copy closure inside the task you looping.

```
task yourtask {

inputs.dir 'some-dir'
outputs.dir 'some-dir'
//or files

  doLast { 
    copy {
      from (sourcePath)
      into (targetPath)
      include '*.jar'
    }
  }
}
```

Note that we wrap it into `doLast` because on the configuration phase
              ist going to be executed as well, even if you didn't call it to execute. `dolast` moves it into the execution phase.

Remember as well about Inputs and outputs to determine whenever the task should or should not be executed, and marked as UP-TO-DATE those are set up already when using a task with a type of a `Copy`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response . It worked perfectly now.

Comment: Well, you can remove the task in this code example, because it won't do anything. Instead it uses the `copy` method and, because you did not wrap it into a `doFirst` or `doLast` closure, it will be executed every time you call `gradle <...>`, completely independent from your task. This is a perfect example for **not** understanding basic Gradle principles.

Comment: @lu.koerfer I will roll it back to the previous edit, it was just to show the concept, i did ask about how and what is the task he is using, i mentioned that the copy closure goes into the doLAst{} and the outputs and inputs should be checked as well.